# How to copy and rename all files in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to copy all jpeg files from a directory (with multiple subdirectories) to a single directory. There are multiple files with the same name, so I am trying to rename the files using the name of the parent directory. For example: c:\images\tiger\image_00001.jpg will be moved to a new folder and renamed to c:\images\allimages\tiger_image_00001.jpg. I tried the code below, but nothing happens. The folder gets created, but the files do not move. This is what I have so far:

```
import os
path = 'source/'
os.mkdir('source/allimages/')
extensions = ['.jpeg']
for folder, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if folder == path or folder == os.path.join(path, 'allimages'):
            continue
        folder = folder.strip(path)
        extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[-1].lower()
        if extension in extensions:
            infilename = os.path.join(path, folder, filename)
            newname = os.path.join(path, 'all_files', "{}-{}".format(folder.strip('./')))
            os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Comment: What is not working with the current approach?

Comment: Change \ to \\ or /. Also, what supposed to be '\source\'? If it's a relative path then it should be 'source/' or './source/'

Comment: So essentially nothing happens. It creates a folder, and that's about it. The files do not move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a function dedicated to resolving a unique filename. A `while` loop should do the trick. This should work.

```
import os
import shutil

def resolve_path(filename, destination_dir):
    dest = os.path.join(destination_dir, filename)
    *base_parts, extension = filename.split('.')
    base_name = '.'.join(base_parts)
    duplicate_num = 1
    while os.path.exists(dest):
        new_base = base_name + str(duplicate_num).zfill(5)
        new_filename = "{}.{}".format(new_base, extension)
        dest = os.path.join(destination_dir, new_filename)
        duplicate_num += 1
    return dest
```

That is such that the following is the result....

```
>>> with open('/path/to/file.extension', 'w') as f:
>>>     pass # just create the file
>>> resolve_path('file.extension', '/path/to/')
'/path/to/file00001.extension'
```

Then put it together with traversing the source...

```
def consolidate(source, destination, extension='.jpg'):
    if not os.path.exists(destination):
        os.makedirs(destination)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for f in files:
            if f.lower().endswith(extension):
                source_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                destination_path = resolve_path(f, destination)
                shutil.copyfile(source_path, destination_path)
```

Comment: So I tried the following code and essentially the program goes into a loop wherein it keeps creating millions of files.
Sample file name: img_0000005502070.jpg

Comment: @user40929 I updated the answer recently. I tested it and it shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing. If this worked for you, be sure to mark the answer as accepted. Cheers and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling splitext on its own output, which doesn't get what you want:

```
In [4]: os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext('foo.bar')[0])[-1]
Out[4]: ''
```

You just want `extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()`, or if you don't want the dot, then `extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()[1:]`.

(Edited) more seriously, there's a problem with `folder.strip(path)`: this will remove *all characters in path* from folder. For instance `'source/rescue'.strip('source/') == ''`. What you want is `folder.replace(path, '')`.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion, but not sure what went wrong. I get the new folder, but the files are not copied.

Comment: @user40929 - see my edited answer above. If that still doesn't do it, I'd recommend adding some print statements to ensure you're really getting to the parts of your code that do the work. For instance, put `print(extension)` before `if extension in extensions:` and see what it looks like. That sort of thing.